# how to prevent of resubmission the form by multiple clicking on submit button?

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I have use Laravel 9 and in a blade I have form below:

```
<form id="create-offline-payment-form" action="{{route ('user.cart.pay')}}" method="post">
     @csrf
     <input type="hidden" value="{{$shop_id}}" id="shop-id" name="shop_id">
     <button  id="payment" type="submit" class="btn">پرداخت آفلاین</button>
</form>
```

the form submit to this method:

```
public function payCart(Request $request)
{
    Transaction::create([
        'seller_id' => Auth::id(),
        'amount' =>  $this->cartSum(),
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('user.cart.paid');
}
```

and in the another method by route above, will show a view to user :

route('user.cart.paid') go to method below:

```
public function paidCart()
{
    return view('user.cart.paid');
}
```

my problem is when a user click several times on submit botton, multiple record gonna be built on Transaction table.

how can I prevent that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form#id').submit(function(){
    $(this).find(':input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).